How do I use toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior for TapGestureRecognizer PanUpdated
How can I use toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior for TapGestureRecognizer Event: PanUpdated, I mean I want to convert something like this:
<Ellipse.GestureRecognizers>
  <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="some_event"></PanGestureRecognizer>
</Ellipse.GestureRecognizers>

to something like this:
<Ellipse.GestureRecognizers>
  <PanGestureRecognizer.Behaviours>
    <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
      EventName="PanUpdated"
      Command="{Binding PanUpdatedCommand}" />
  </PanGestureRecognizer.Behaviours>
</Ellipse.GestureRecognizers>

But I can't use PanGestureRecognizer.Behaviours. So my question how do I use EventToCommandBehavior for PanUpdated?
Edit:
My case is like this: I have PanX, PanY and I need them in my ViewModel because they will be passed to the repository layer. PanX and PanY come from the calculation of event.TotalX and event.TotalY from the PanUpdated event. Therefore, I need to store them in my ViewModel. In the UI layer it looks like a joystick, when I move the ellipse, I need to immediately send these coordinates to let say the backend. So I would like to use PanGestureRecognizer.

So, I wasn't clear enough? Right now I can separate and reuse almost all of my code, thanks to following MVVM pattern. Like 90% or so. (The messy part is "maui issue workarounds" and platform specific android/ios non-sense.) You want to add your interface to View Model? No problem. PanGestureRecognizer has EventHandler "PanUpdated".  EventToCommand behavior has a delegate. I can max those and give you something working. I can make you custom Ellipse control with bindable command property. And you will mess your project beyond repair. It is better to not use MVVM at all.

Why do you want your View manipulation code in your ViewModel?

Please take a look at the post, I added more information in the edit.

If you use PanGestureRecognizer, you will deal with the view's moving that will refer to the view's TranslationX and TranslationX property. This will indeed violate the MVVM policy.

You can't use the toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior for PanGestureRecognizer in MAUI. It's not supported.
In addition, you shouldn't do this. For the PanGestureRecognizer, you will deal with the view's moving that will refer to the view's TranslationX and TranslationX  property. This violates the MVVM policy.
If you don't have to deal with the view's moving. You can just use the  DragGestureRecognizer and DropGestureRecognizer, the two gestures provide a Command property.

I support this answer. Bringing this event to View Model violates MVVM policy.

What about a case like this: I have PanX, PanY and I need them in my ViewModel because they will be passed to the repository layer. PanX and PanY come from the calculation of event.TotalX and event.TotalY from the PanUpdated event. Therefore, I need to store them in my ViewModel. In the UI layer it looks like a joystick, when I move the ellipse, I need to immediately send these coordinates to let say the backend.

Take a look at this: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/tree/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Views/Expander , public class Joystick : ContentView, internal PanGestureRecognizer, HandlePanUpdated, public static BindableProperty CommandProperty, and the command goes in your ViewModel.

And this solution is the one which that can mess my project? I am confused, I don't know which solution is the best.

No, this one is ok. The code is inside your custom control. It is part of the View. The ViewModel gets the command: "Send to backend API  power=3 , angle = 35  degree." It has no clue about how this is calculated, what it means, what kind of event is behind it, etc. All this is handled in your Joystic.cs. Instead of Command, you can also use "Messenger". And last note - there are so many examples for joystick for xamarin forms. You can "get inspiration" from their GitHub code, where such controls have been implemented. No need to reinvent the wheel.
